# Some examples and non-examples of topological manifolds (w boundary or not)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, manifolds-with-boundary

I'm trying to check if these spaces are topological manifolds (i.e. locally euclidean and $T_2$) with or without boundary.

I would like to know if I made any mistakes, both in the answers or in the reasoning leading to them (i.e. if I give the correct answer for the wrong reasons).

**1. $D^2$ the closed disk in $\mathbb{R}^2,$ quotiented by identifying all points on $S^1.$**

> I think this is not a topological manifold: indeed, I can identify
> $D^2$ with the half sphere $S^2_{\geq 0}$, and under this
> homeomorphism (which takes $(x,y)$ to $(x,y,1-x^2-y^2$)) the points on
> $S^1$ are left fixed.
>
> Hence, contracting $S^1$ to the point the half sphere becomes
> something like a baloon.
>
> The baloon is not a manifold since a neighborhood of the point $P$
> corresponding to $S^1$ will become contractible after removing $P,$
> while something homeomorphic to a disk would retract to $S^1$ after
> removing a point.
>
> On the other hand, I think it is a manifold with boundary, where the
> only boundary point is $P$. This is because a neighborhood of $P$ will
> be homeomorphic to the positive ($x\geq 0, y\geq0$) portion of a disk
> centered in $0$ by a homeomorphism sending $P \mapsto 0.$

**2. The closed disk $D^2,$ quotiented by identifying the diameter given by all $(x,0)$ with $-1 \leq x \leq 1.$**

> This is not a top. manifold because a point on $S^1$ will have a
> neighborhood that will be contractible after removing a point.
>
> I think it is not a manifold with boundary. Indeed if I picture this
> space as a disk with the diameter pinched to the center $0$, then taking
> a neighborhood of $0$ and removing $0$ from it I get two connected
> components, while a half disk of $\mathbb{R}^2$ remains connected
> after removing any point.

**3. The closed disk $D^2$ where you identify $(-1,0)\sim (1,0)$**

> Certainly this is not a topological manifold for the same reason as
> above. I think this is a manifold with boundary; in this case the
> boundary is given by all points on $S^1$ except for $(1,0) \sim
>  (-1,0),$ since these points have a neighborhood homeomorphic to a
> disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- A balloon is exactly the same thing as $S^2$, so it *is* a manifold without boundary.

Your argument does not work: why would a neighbourhood of $P$ become contractible after removing $P$ ?

2- Your justification is correct, although you only really need the second part (indeed, half disks *and* disks remain connected when you remove a point)

3- It is not a manifold with boundary: the points that are identified have no neighbourhood that is a disk or a half disk (for the same reason as above)

Comment: for 1: Yes you are right I was confusing myself. For 3: I don't see how I can use the same reasoning as 2. I was thinking that if I have a neighborhood of $(-1,0)$, which is a half disk, then after identifying $(0,1)\sim (-1.0)$ I would get the other half of the disk. In any case I don't see why those points can't have a neighborhood homeomorphic to a disk or half disk...

Comment: For 2: I wanted to say that even without looking at the identification on the diameter we still can't have a top. manifold without boundary beacause points on $S^1$ will have ngbhds homeomorphic to half disks and not disks.

Comment: If you remove that point, the neighbourhood has two connected components. You don't get the other half of the disk because the boundary points other than $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$ are not identified

Comment: You are right of course about the other half of the disk. I still don't see why I get two connected components..

Comment: A neighbourhood of this point will be two half disks connected by a single point on their boundary. If you remove that point, you get two half disks, i.e. two connected components

Comment: ah now I see. The source of my confusion was that If I had two half disks glued along a line I get a full disk, but as you pointed out in this case they are glued just on a point.

Comment: Yes, exactly ! That's what I tried to point out earlier, but it's not as easy without drawings...